# Problemas com a utilização do include no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Estou com problemas a função include, de acordo com a documentação do django, a sintaxe é  `include(module, namespace=None)`,
`include(pattern_list)`,`include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)`.

---

### Código fonte

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('clientes/', include("cliente.urls", namespace="cliente")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

### Erro

```
path('clientes/', include("cliente.urls", namespace="cliente")),
File "/home/phomint/DjangoProjects/Manager/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include

'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name  attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.
```

Comment: Olhou a documentação da versão certa? As informações da pergunta diferem da documentação da 1.11: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#include

Comment: Olhei sim no meu projeto estou usando a v2.1 e olhei a documentação referente a ela. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Você precisa incluir o app_name no urls.py do app cliente e não no arquivo urls.py que você deseja colocar o include. Por isso continua dando o erro.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme você escreveu, a sintaxe pode ser

`include((pattern_list, app_namespace), namespace=None)`

Então no seu caso:

`path('clientes/', include(("cliente.urls", "cliente"), namespace="cliente"))`

Answer (score 0):

No seu arquivo `cliente.urls` crie uma variável `app_name='cliente'`.

**Exemplo**:

```
"""Arquivos urls.py que está em cliente"""
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='cliente'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Apenas criar essa variável não muda nada, tenho que chama lá em algum outro local ?

Comment: Simulei o erro aqui.
Dai quando adiciono `app_name='cliente'` no arquivo `cliente/urls.py` o erro para.
Quando comento a variável `# app_name='cliente'` o erro é igual ao que você postou.
Basicamente só adicionando essa variável deveria funcionar.
O único lugar que encontrei referencia a esse erro foi no `django-rest-framework`, segue referencia:
[Github do django-rest-framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5851).

Comment: Localizei na documentação do Django a referencia ao `app_name`:
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/http/urls/#id5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/http/urls/#id5)

Comment: Então dei uma lida na documentação e tentei mesmo da sua forma, porém o erro continua, com o `include` estou direcionando para o arquivo de urls do clientes e preciso declarar o `namespace` para pode chamar ele na view. Funciona parecido com o `app_name` mas ele é para dar o nome para o próprio arquivo url. @RenatoCruz